# How can I assure icon text contrast against a changing background?

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization, themes, accessibility, readability

My desktop covers three screens, each with its own image. One image is mainly dark green and blue, and white icon text is legible over it; another is light – mainly sky -- and black icon text works well over it. But all three images have both light and dark areas.

I would like the icon text to be set automatically for best contrast with the background where it is located. Is that possible?

Currently my icon text is shadowed. You would think that would create the necessary contrast for light text to be visible on a light background, but I find that all I really see is the dark outline – the text within is too spindly to be easily read.

If it is not possible to have the text color set individually based on the background where it is located, is there a way to set the color on a screen-by-screen basis?

My OS is Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Would this at least partialy solve your problem?

Navigate to "**Advanced System Settings**". You can do so either by typing "Advanced System Settings" in the Start menu, or going to **Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced System Settings**.

Then go to **Advanced tab** > click **settings** in the **Performance** section.

The last option in **Visual Effects** should be **Use drop shadows for icon labels on the desktop** (Or if it's not last, look for it). Disable that, restart the system and check the font color. They should now change to black or white according to their background.